# Web app controlling a physical device

Tags: web-applications, network-programming, arduino

I have set myself the challenge to create a (probably) Arduino powered mechanical device that could be controlled via a web application. So I want a web application to send over the web a certain command to the computer connected to Arduino, but I don't even know what to begin with—programming languages, tools, libraries... I'm a web designer/developer, but I've never done any “real” programming, therefore I would be very very happy if anyone could just point me in the right direction.

So far it seems I might need to make use of node.js. I'm thinking the user would click on a button that would trigger a script that should be read on the other end in real time—how would I go about that?

I do appreciate anyone reading this and thanks for any reply!

Answer (score 0):

I would use an [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) server library (on the device, or close to it) like e.g. [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), and code the application in a low level language like C or C++.

Maybe use a low-cost embedded Linux system like [Rasberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org) or [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/)

And before that, learn Linux (& C, if so needed) by installing it on your laptop and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

PS I don't think that [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is relevant.

Comment: The question did say "computer connected to Arduino" so it's possible that the intention was to host the web server (which could be node.js using Socket.IO for fast reaction times) on that computer which then sends commands to the arduino via some other interface.